# The ViewData item that has the key 'City' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
 <div class="form-box-left">
        <h5>*City :</h5>
     @Html.DropDownList("City", null, "Select City",new { @class="text-box",Id="City"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
  </div>

     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PostRequirement(string Username)
    {
        ViewBag.City = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "City");
        ViewBag.citylist = _data.getCity();
        ViewBag.BudgetMin = new SelectList(db.Budgets, "Budgetid", "Budget");
        ViewBag.BudgetMax = new SelectList(db.Budgets, "Budgetid", "Budget");
        ViewBag.Locality = new SelectList(db.Areas, "Locality_Id", "Locality");

        return View();
    }
```

I am trying to  store the city name in database using dropdownlist but getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the select list.

Try do this.

```
@Html.DropDownList(
   "City",
   new SelectList(ViewBag.citylist, "TheCityIdProperty", "TheCityTextOrNameProperty"),
   "Select City",
   new { @class="text-box",Id="City"})
```